# Time difference calculation error

Tags: java, time, duration, timezone-offset, datetimeoffset

I have to calculate total fly time minutes between departure airport and arrival airport.

This job is done by this code snippet:

```
    public int calculateFlightDuration(String departureDateTime, String depAirportCode, String arrivalDateTime,
        String arrAirportCode) {
    try {
        LocalDateTime depLocalTime = LocalDateTime.parse(departureDateTime, formatter);
        LocalDateTime arrLocalTime = LocalDateTime.parse(arrivalDateTime, formatter);

        ZoneOffset depZoneOffset = getTimeZoneOffset(depAirportCode);
        ZoneOffset arrZoneOffset = getTimeZoneOffset(arrAirportCode);

        if (depZoneOffset != null && arrZoneOffset != null) {

            OffsetDateTime offsetDepTime = OffsetDateTime.of(depLocalTime, depZoneOffset);
            OffsetDateTime offsetArrTime = OffsetDateTime.of(arrLocalTime, arrZoneOffset);

            Duration flightDuration = Duration.between(offsetArrTime, offsetDepTime).abs();

            return (int) flightDuration.toMinutes();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.warn("::calculateFlightDuration depTime:{} dep.code:{} arrTime:{} arr.code:{}", departureDateTime,
                depAirportCode, arrivalDateTime, arrAirportCode);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the problem:

When I want to calculate future flight's duration with those parameters:

```
depLocalTime = 2017-11-06T14:50
arrLocalTime = 2017-11-06T16:45
depZoneOffset = +03:00
arrZoneOffset = +02:00
```

as a result of those parameters, flightDuration object is:

```
flightDuration = PT2H55M
```

Seems everything is OK, right? But it's not OK actually. Let me explain;

The departure airport code is IST (Turkey) and arrival airport code is AMS (Netherlands) and here is the key:

After 2017-10-29 (before the time I calculated), AMS time will be backed by 1 hour, and its offset will be +01:00, and the IST offset still remain +03:00. So the correct duration object have to be:

```
flightDuration = PT3H55M
```

How can I fix this problem? It's really annoying.
Thanks for your help.

Edit after ZonedDateTime comments:

Guys, I also tried with ZonedDateTime object, on calculations. Here is the code with ZonedDateTime object used, it makes no difference on the result.

```
    public int calculateFlightDuration(String departureDateTime, String depAirportCode, String arrivalDateTime,
        String arrAirportCode) {
    try {
        LocalDateTime depLocalTime = LocalDateTime.parse(departureDateTime, formatter);
        LocalDateTime arrLocalTime = LocalDateTime.parse(arrivalDateTime, formatter);

        ZoneOffset depZoneOffset = getTimeZoneOffset(depAirportCode);
        ZoneOffset arrZoneOffset = getTimeZoneOffset(arrAirportCode);

        if (depZoneOffset != null && arrZoneOffset != null) {

            ZonedDateTime zonedDepTime = ZonedDateTime.of(depLocalTime, depZoneOffset);
            ZonedDateTime zonedArrTime = ZonedDateTime.of(arrLocalTime, arrZoneOffset);

//              OffsetDateTime offsetDepTime = OffsetDateTime.of(depLocalTime, depZoneOffset);
//              OffsetDateTime offsetArrTime = OffsetDateTime.of(arrLocalTime, arrZoneOffset);

            Duration flightDuration = Duration.between(zonedDepTime, zonedArrTime).abs();

            return (int) flightDuration.toMinutes();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.warn("::calculateFlightDuration depTime:{} dep.code:{} arrTime:{} arr.code:{}", departureDateTime,
                depAirportCode, arrivalDateTime, arrAirportCode);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After the @Joe C 's answer, I changed the code again and I believe that this is the way I should go:

```
    public int calculateFlightDuration(String departureDateTime, String depAirportCode, String arrivalDateTime,
        String arrAirportCode) {
    try {
        LocalDateTime depLocalTime = LocalDateTime.parse(departureDateTime, formatter);
        LocalDateTime arrLocalTime = LocalDateTime.parse(arrivalDateTime, formatter);

        ZoneId depZoneId = getTimeZoneId(depAirportCode);
        ZoneId arrZoneId = getTimeZoneId(arrAirportCode);

        if (depZoneId != null && arrZoneId != null) {

            ZonedDateTime zonedDepTime = ZonedDateTime.of(depLocalTime, depZoneId);
            ZonedDateTime zonedArrTime = ZonedDateTime.of(arrLocalTime, arrZoneId);

            Duration flightDuration = Duration.between(zonedDepTime, zonedArrTime).abs();

            return (int) flightDuration.toMinutes();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.warn("::calculateFlightDuration depTime:{} dep.code:{} arrTime:{} arr.code:{}", departureDateTime,
                depAirportCode, arrivalDateTime, arrAirportCode);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

BUT: Java assumes that Istanbul also change its timezone offset to +02:00, but IT WILL NOT HAPPEN. I think I also need to get my Java updated. Here is the result after code change:

```
depZoneId = Europe/Istanbul
arrZoneId = Europe/Amsterdam
zonedDepTime = 2017-11-06T14:50+02:00[Europe/Istanbul] //damn it's really annoying!
zonedArrTime = 2017-11-06T16:45+01:00[Europe/Amsterdam]
```

aaand flight duration remains the same:

```
flightDuration = PT2H55M
```

Thanks for the answers guys. Now I have to fix the timezone change of Istanbul.

Comment: Hint - you need to use `ZonedDateTime` instead of `OffsetDateTime`.  I hope that's enough information to help you work it out.  I'll write a complete answer if I have time later.

Comment: Hi @Jesper, thats because the difference have to be PT3H55M at 2017-11-06. On this date, the offset of the AMS will be +01:00.

Comment: But the flight will not suddenly be 1 hour longer just because AMS switched to winter time?

Comment: You are definitely right :) It's just a representation of the difference between two local times, it might be confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) assumes a common offset for the entire year (ex. UTC+2).  It does not cover anything along the lines of Summer Time.

If you want to account for Summer Time, you should use a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) instead, with a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html).  In the case of [`Europe/Amsterdam`](https://time.is/Amsterdam), it will select either UTC+1 or UTC+2 depending on the time of year.

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDepTime = ZonedDateTime.of(depLocalTime, ZoneId.of("Asia/Istanbul"));
ZonedDateTime zonedArrTime = ZonedDateTime.of(arrLocalTime, ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam"));
```